# How to increase the value of an object key with a key variable?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
const obj = {foo: 1, bar: 1};
```

And a data items. e.g.:

```
const data = {who: "foo", task: "jump"};
const data = {who: "foo", task: "run"};
const data = {who: "bar", task: "jump"};
```

And I want to increase a value of the object based on the who key of the data item.

Like if `data.who === "foo"` increase `obj[data.who]` by 1.
The issue I'm having is, that I don't know that foo is foo and bar is bar. Thus `data.who === "foo"` is not working, as I don't know foo.

Comment: please explain more

Comment: `if (data.who in obj) obj[data.who]++` ?

Comment: `obj[data.who] = obj[data.who] ? obj[data.who] += 1 : 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const tasks: {who: string, task: string}[] = [
  {who: "foo", task: "jump"},
  {who: "foo", task: "run"},
  {who: "bar", task: "jump"},
]
const obj: {[who: string]: number} = {}
for (const data of tasks)
  obj[data.who] = (obj[data.who] ?? 0) + 1
```

to add keys to `obj` dynamically, if you don't know them in advance.

Or, using `reduce`:

```
const obj = tasks.reduce<{[who:string]:number}>((counts, data) => ({
  ...counts,
  [data.who]: (counts[data.who]??0) + 1
}), {})
```

Comment: [Will add `0` to `obj` if the key isn't in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70348335/how-to-increase-the-value-of-an-object-key-with-a-key-variable/70348499#comment124354560_70348394)

Comment: In the second solution I think you need `(counts[data.who] ?? 0)` instead of `(data.who??0)`.

Comment: @aerial301 You're right.

Comment: @jsejcksn You're wrong. There aren't any keys in it to begin with, so it'll add 1 or nothing.

Comment: @DustInCompetent You're right about it being `1` The point I was making is that you're also adding additional properties to the object which didn't exist before.

Comment: @jsejcksn That's intentional, the question says the keys are unknown ahead of time, so you'll have to add them as you find them in the input tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj[data["who"]]++;
```

should work if the only "who" values are "foo" and "bar"

Comment: Will add `NaN`s to `obj` if the key isn't in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional to check if the property exists on the object and that its value is a `number` type before trying to increment it:

```js
const obj = {foo: 1, bar: 1};

const dataItems = [
  {who: 'foo', task: 'jump'},
  {who: 'foo', task: 'run'},
  {who: 'bar', task: 'jump'},
  {who: 'baz', task: 'jump'},
];

for (const data of dataItems) {
  const key = data.who;
  if (typeof obj[key] === 'number') {
    obj[key] += 1;
  }
  else {
    console.log(`The object does not have a number value at "${key}".`);
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```